# Strcture in C. (Pointers Usage and to show relations)

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to show that first two citizen are married together in 2009 using pointers (let's say citiens are Anthony Hopkins and Jodie Foster)

```
struct citizen
{
char sSSC[12];
char sFamilyName[16];
char sNames[24];
char cGender; //men ='m', women='w'
citizen*pSpouse; //Null if not married
int iYearOfMarriage;

}
citizen People[100000];
```

Comment: Do you want a boolean answer regarding the first two entries  (People[0] and People[1]) or do you want to find the first two maried citizen entries?

Comment: What's the problem?  Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: Do you allow same gender marriage?

Comment: The Boolean answer for the given example would be `false`.

Comment: Choose Scarlett Johansson, she is beautiful.

Comment: I now pronounce you 0x804a9c0 and 0x8054200.  You may kiss the bride.

Comment: You've tagged the question C but you're using `new`?

Comment: @termius I want boolean answer regarding the first two (People[0] and People[1])

Comment: @pmg unfortunately no. I hope "you won't mind it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, just:

```
People[ANTHONY_HOPKINS].pSpouse = &People[JODIE_FOSTER];
People[JODIE_FOSTER].pSpouse = &People[ANTHONY_HOPKINS];
People[ANTHONY_HOPKINS].iYearOfMarriage = 
People[JODIE_FOSTER].iYearOfMarriage = 2009;
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question? '.' is used to reference members in a struct (or -> if you have a pointer to a struct), '&' is a pointer to that symbol.

You'll probably also want to declare that as:

```
struct citizen *pSpouse;
```

Leaving the 'struct' as implicit is supported in C++ but not in C (though if you have a pure-C++ compiler then you can mostly use it for C code, with the odd thing like that not reported as an error when it should be).

Addition:

To test whether records 0 and 1 are married:

```
if(People[0].pSpouse == &People[1])
{
    printf("They're married!\n");
}
```

Comparing the value of pointers is always a valid way to check whether they point to the same thing.

Comment: I need to use pointers and mark pointer to show they are married. I wrote above how I am trying to do.

Comment: So you want to be able to test whether they're married? I've amended my answer if that's it.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks a lot. Sometimes it's a bit difficult for new beginners to explain or even ask in proper terms but you got it :) so once again Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
People[0].pSpouse = &People[1];
People[0].iYearOfMarriage = 2009; 

People[1].pSpouse = &People[0];
People[1].iYearOfMarriage = 2009;
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed before:
1> If using c compiler use
typedef struct citizen {
...
} citizen;

And
allPeople[0].spouse = &allPeople[1];

allPeople[1].spouse = &allPeople[0];